# Capturing Console output to Azure ApplicationInsights in asp.net core app

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, azure-application-insights

I am using ApplicationInsight provider with an ASP.NET Core app to log to the Azure ApplicationInsight resource. This works fine and I can see all .LogInformation traces plus all dependencies/exceptions in the Azure  ApplicationInsights viewer.

However, some projects within the solution happen to use  'Console.WriteLine("");' code for logging. I need to capture/redirect these logs to ApplicationInsights provider so that all my logs are in a cloud. Unfortunately, I can not modify the code in these projects  and replace these lines with .LogInformation - that would be too easy. Is  there a way to do this by making changes to either application.config or code within Startup or Program classes only? Perhaps there is a Azure  AppService configuration that would do that?

Answer (score 1):

Only below logging frameworks are supported as of now:

- ILogger
- Log4Net, NLog, or System.Diagnostics.Trace
- Java, Log4J, or Logback
- LogStash plugin
- Azure Monitor

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/platforms#logging-frameworks

You can use ILogger to send you console logs to application insights by making changes in the Program.cs and Startup.cs

https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/255

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger